# jQuery sibling selector?

Tags: jquery

I have a table which I'm trying to do a pricing list, that auto-computes the tax component..

I'm getting the value from price_1, applying a math cal, and saving it to tax_1. I could read the number of the end of the id, but hopefully there is a cleaner way with jQuery.

E.g. I would have a lot of fields like..

- price_1
- price_2
- price_3
- tax_1
- tax_2
- tax_3 etc...

I can use the following code to call jQuery on change of a price, and get the value of that price. How do I update the tax field next to it? should I use a sibling selector or something??

```
$('#pricing').delegate("input", "change", function(){

  $(this).val() /* the value of the price */; 

})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i will need some HTML to give a better answer, but what you asking for is really simple.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".price").blur(function() {  // when the price input loses focus
        var price = $(this).val();     
        var tax = price * 1.15; // use whatever formula you need here, this is for Mexico.
        $(this).next().val(tax);
    }
});
```

this is of course assuming there is an input showing the tax amount next to every price input.
if you decide to use a Label or a Span just change `$(this).next().val(tax);` to `$(this).next().text(tax);`

Answer (score 0):

If tax field is present next to the price as you say, you can use the **[`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/)** in order to select that. It would be better if you post your html too.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your dom structure, but generally you could have something like

```
var commonParent = 'tr'; // a common parent for finding related nodes

$('#pricing').delegate("input", "change", function(){

  var val = $(this).val() /* the value of the price */; 
  var tax = val;

  $(this).parents(commonParent).find('input[name=*tax]').val(tax);
})
```